# ActionBar back button does not work

Tags: android

I have an action bar containing a search view.when i want to search something from my list view by clicking search button, action bar shows a back button on the left side.if i click this back button after getting search list, search view and back button disappear but the list View shows only that searched list not original list.

```
public class ActivityThree extends AppCompatActivity{
FloatingActionButton fab;
DBHelper myDb;
ArrayList<AccountDetails> rList;
ListView listView;
RemainderAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_three);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myDb = new DBHelper(this);

    showViews();
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityThree.this, ActivityFour.class));
        }
    });
}



private void showViews() {
    rList = new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();
    rList = myDb.getAllRows();
    if (rList.size() != 0) {
        adapter = new RemainderAdapter(this, rList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"There is no item in the list",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
    {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
    {

        adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
};
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.changePwd){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PwdChange.class));
        return true;
    }
    if(id==R.id.about){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityAbout.class));
        return true;
    }if(id==R.id.share){
        try
        { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ABCD");
            String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose any one"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
        }
    }
    if(id==R.id.exit){
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: How can i get original list by clicking this back button? thanks in advance

Comment: set listadapter again.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! post your code too.

Comment: Did you use toolbar widget?

Comment: @Masum,no i did not use toolbar widget

Comment: @diya visit this link : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Extended-ActionBar-Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code that is showing a toast when `searchView's` back button clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," Back Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showViews();
            return true;
        }
    });

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Comment: ,i putted this code in onCreateOptionsMenu.but it did not work.pls say where i put the this codes(which you sent).i posted my code.pls check it

Comment: i updated my code. when the searchview is expanded and you clicks back button the `showViews()` will be called and the same adapter with whole dataset will be attach to list.

Comment: but it is not working.i have posted my codes.pls kindly set your code in my onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu),then it will be better for me to understand.thanks in advance

Comment: if you can send me the project at droidwithme@gmail.com i will figure it with testing and will post the answer here as well.

Comment: then where i set my SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

Comment: i again updated and tested my code just copy and pest.

Comment: accept the answer it may help others happy coding :)